# Using MaxLength attribute in .Net Standard 1.2

Tags: c#, .net-standard, .net-framework-version, maxlength

My main project is stuck into .Net framework 4.5.1 and references a project in .Net Standard.
For compatibility reasons I can't upgrade .Net Standard over 1.2.
The .Net Standard project needs to declare models with a `[MaxLength()]` attribute from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, but this attribute is only available in 2.0 version.

Is there a workaround to have `[MaxLength()]` attribute in standard 1.2?

**EDIT**
I already tried to implement it myself, but as I could expect it's not taken into account by the upper Entity Framework layer.

[image]

Comment: what kind of application is this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe creating your own `[MaxLength]`, inheriting from `ValidationAttribute`?

you can take a look, or maybe just copy paste [the current implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/7c3c88d490ae557241aa838695063415822dc692/src/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/MaxLengthAttribute.cs#L15)

Answer (score 0):

You can write it yourself)

```
public class MyMaxLenght : ValidationAttribute
{
    private int _lenght;
    public MyMaxLenght(int lenght)
    {
        _lenght = lenght;
    }
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            return value.ToString().Length > _lenght ? true : false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Using:

```
public class Test
{
    [MyMaxLenght(2)]
    public string Name;
}
```

Or using

> [MaxLength()]

from

> using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;